# ajax call can't pass parameters and work only with some browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have problem with this this function that should make an ajax call:

```
function updateCountriesPrice(){
        var countryFrom = select_country_from.options[select_country_from.selectedIndex].value;

        var countriesTo = JSON.parse("[" + $('#countriesToUpdate').val() + "]");
        var arrayProductCode = [];
            arrayProductCode=localStorage.list_id.replace(/ /g,'');
        var data = {'products_list': arrayProductCode,
                        'country_from': countryFrom,
                        'countries_to': countriesTo};
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: './products_actions_prices',  //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            //Ajax events

            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                $('#div_action_selected').html('').hide();
                jQuery('#wrapper').append('<div class="flash success" >'+jqXHR.responseJSON.text+'</div>');
                setTimeout(function(){$('.flash').slideUp(1000);},3000);
                $('#div_action_selected').html('').hide();
                jQuery.each(jQuery('.check_box'),function(key,value){
                    if(jQuery('#select_all').is(':checked')){
                        $(this).prop('checked', false);
                    }
                });
                $('#select_all').prop('checked', false);//$('#select_actions').hide();
                $('#select_all_products_div').hide();
                localStorage.clear();localStorage.setItem('list_id','');
                setInterval(location.reload(),2500);
                hideDivAction();

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $('#div_action_selected').html('<div id=\"errorExplanation\" class=\"errorExplanation\" data-hook=\"\">'
                    +' <h2>One error prohibited this action:</h2>'
                    +' <p>There were problems with the call.</p>'
                    +' </div>');
                    setTimeout(function(){$('#div_action_selected').slideUp(1000);},3000);
                    //$('#select_actions').attr('value','');
            },
            // Form data
            data: data,
            //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });


    }
```

Using chrome the call work and i see the success result, but my params variable doesn't contains the data that i pass with ajax. 
When I call 
    console.log(data);
I can see the datas exactly as i want them but they doesn't arrive to my rails controller.

Using firefox the ajax either start.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `params` variable. If you're talking about the `data` object containing `products_list` etc., you've not added that to the Ajax request.

Comment: I meen the params variable of my rails controller. Why you say that I've not added that to Ajax request? I follow lots of guide and i found this syntax

Comment: You're not sending any data in the Ajax like `$.ajax({ data: data`

Comment: He means you are not sending data in your ajax request. $.ajax(url: "url", data: {any: "data"})

Comment: Hey, guys, @TWONEKSONE is sending data, at the end of the query... In my opinion, the issue is the "processData".

Comment: already try process data :true. Doesn't work!

Comment: What about the fact that the request start only with some browser?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `dataType`.

According to [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/),

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, **json**, script, or html))
>   Type: String
>   The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

Comment: Which dataType should i use if i pass 2 string and one array. I thought the default value should work.

Comment: The dataType you should pass depend on your data.
According to your question I don't know which data type you are using.
Are you trying to send an XML/ JSON to the server?